# I need to write a script that adds all arguments to a Python list, and then save them to a file

Tags: python, json

for some reason the file is saving as a "list of lists"

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import json
save_to_json_file = __import__('5-save_to_json_file').save_to_json_file
load_from_json_file = __import__('6-load_from_json_file').load_from_json_file

args = sys.argv
filename = "add_item.json"
with open(filename, 'a+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(args[1:])
    save_to_json_file(my_list, filename)
    load_from_json_file(filename)
```

[this is the file that is creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o41H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args[1:]` is a slice - it returns a list, which you append to a list, making a list of lists.

Perhaps you want `my_list = args[1:]`? Otherwise, you can use `my_list.extend(args[1:])`